# Dart Polymer 1.0 is there any way to use one "refectable" class on client and server side?

Tags: dart, polymer-1.0, mutation-observers

Using JsProxy in `Dart Polymer 1.0` to enable two-way binding not allow to use this classes on server side. Extending from parent class with `JsProxy` also does not solve the problem.

As I tried to work around this problem. I create a class (to using on server side) and then extends from this with `JsProxy`:

```
class Person {
    @reflectable String name;
    @reflectable int age;

    Person(this.name, this.age);
}

class PersonModel extends Person with JsProxy {
    PersonModel(name, age) : super(name, age);
}
```

Object `person` does not reflect changes if i change value using `set`

```
<my-element>
    <p>[[person.name]], [[person.age]]</p>
</my-element>

void main() {
    PersonModel person;
    set('person', new PersonModel('Tom', 23));
}
```

Is there any way to use class on client and server side, without the need to maintain two separate class for the client and server? Maybe there are some other ways to solve this?

Comment: What error message do you get when a class annotated with `@JsProxy` is used on the server?

Comment: The problem is that the server is using `dart:io` library, and `JsProxy` uses `dart:html`. As is known, these libraries can not be used together

Comment: There shouldn't be a need for JsProxy to use `dart:html`. I suggest creating an issue to move the annotation class to a library on its own without `dart:html` import.

Comment: I created https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/issues/664

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the updates on issue https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/issues/664 this is currently not supported but there are plans to get rid of this limitation.

Comment: Thanks for the help and complete answer to my question! Badly that the current state is not maintained, unfortunately, it makes it impossible to use the basic an advantage of dart - the use of one code in the client and server(